# Manga/manhwa about a young, pink-haired girl who is the youngest daughter of a noble family with seven(?) older brothers, all with pink hair

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga/manhwa about a really young girl who was hiding away from her mother, a witch with blue hair, who was deathly ill and sent the young girl away so as to not see her die.

The young girl ends up being found by her father who is a noble(?) man and brings her home to her seven(?) brothers, who all become very protective of her.

I think it was also revealed that she had a past life/went back in time because she was sick with the same curse/illness that her mother had, but her mother had somehow saved her(?) and suffered from the curse/illness instead of the girl.

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[Born as the Second Daughter](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/born-as-the-second-daughter)***...?

> Selene was fortunate to be born to her beloved mother not just once, but twice. And now that her single mother has died in her second life, Selene must face the world as an orphan... or so she thought. Before she knows it, she's swept up by a handsome stranger who turns out to be her father and the nation's emperor! Not only that, but she discovers she has three older brothers who absolutely adore her. Going from the slums to the imperial palace overnight isn't easy, however, and Selene must navigate her family dynamics, the rules of the palace, and the unbearable loneliness of missing her mother. Moreover, Selene begins to realize that there's a hidden reason why she remembers her past life so well. Will Selene be able to find closure from her past and finally mend the hole that her mother's death left in her heart?

The main character, Selene, is a pink-haired young girl who lived in hiding with her mother, a 'wizardess' with blue hair. Her mother fell deathly ill and gave Selene a note with a spell cast on it directing her to head north. On her way, she encountered a man with pink hair, who turned out to be an emperor and her estranged father. He took her back to his palace and introduced her to her three brothers, who each have pink hair as well.

[image: Born as the Second Daughter, chapter 1, page 5 and 6.] [image: Born as the Second Daughter, chapter 3, page 33.]